# Symfony 5.1 choice list filtering

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 5.1 to filter an entity in a form type.

```
->add('ageGroup', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => AgeGroup::class,
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    'choice_filter' => ChoiceList::filter(
        $this,
        function ($ageGroup) {
            if ($ageGroup instanceof AgeGroup) {
                return $ageGroup->getOrganization()->getId() == $this->security->getUser()->getOrganization()->getId();
            }
            return false;
        }
    )
])
->add('room', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => Room::class,
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    'choice_filter' => ChoiceList::filter(
        $this,
        function ($room) {
            if ($room instanceof Room) {
                return $room->getBranch()->getOrganization()->getId() == $this->security->getUser()->getOrganization()->getId();
            }
            return false;
        }
    ),
])
```

I have an interesting issue. Whichever `ChoiceList::filter` is first will work but no other filter will work after.

This is when `->add('ageGroup')` was placed first.
[image]

This is when `->add('room')` was placed first.
[image]

The 2nd choice list is not called. At all.

In fact, no other `ChoiceList::filter` is called if I add more than 1.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html places no limitation on how many can be called.

Clearly I'm doing so

I can't even begin to guess what's wrong with it.

Comment: Have you tried using the third argument to `ChoiceList::filter`? The [code docs](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php#L74) say "$vary: Dynamic data used to compute a unique hash when caching the callback".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ChoiceList::filter` method takes a third argument named `$vary`.

As per the [PHPDoc comment](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php#L74):

```php
/**
 * @param FormTypeInterface|FormTypeExtensionInterface $formType A form type or type extension configuring a cacheable choice list
 * @param mixed                                        $option   Any pseudo callable, array, string or bool to define a choice list option
 * @param mixed|null                                   $vary     Dynamic data used to compute a unique hash when caching the option
 */
```

The hashing function used within this method uses php's built-in [`spl_object_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) on the `$formType` object, which will yield the same id for both callbacks. Pass the field name (or anything else that is unique) as a third argument:

```php
->add('ageGroup', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => AgeGroup::class,
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    'choice_filter' => ChoiceList::filter(
        $this,
        function ($ageGroup) {
            if ($ageGroup instanceof AgeGroup) {
                return $ageGroup->getOrganization()->getId() == $this->security->getUser()->getOrganization()->getId();
            }
            return false;
        },
        'ageGroup'
    )
])
->add('room', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => Room::class,
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    'choice_filter' => ChoiceList::filter(
        $this,
        function ($room) {
            if ($room instanceof Room) {
                return $room->getBranch()->getOrganization()->getId() == $this->security->getUser()->getOrganization()->getId();
            }
            return false;
        },
        'room'
    ),
])
```